# looking for a different verb for "provides"

Tags: word-request, verbs

I am looking for a different verb, bolded, (or a different way of description) for the following sentence -

> "In summary, this work provides a detailed description of the enzyme catalyic mechanism, which **provides** an important insight into the molecular basis of XYZ disease."

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In summary, this work provides a detailed description of the enzyme catalyic mechanism, which **reveals** an important insight into the molecular basis of XYZ disease."

Answer (score 1):

The verb **provides** appears twice in one sentence.

> In summary, this work **provides** a detailed description of the enzyme
>   catalyic mechanism, which **provides** an important insight into the
>   molecular basis of XYZ disease.

It would be easy to change the first one, as the second seems correct.

> In summary, this work **is** a detailed description of the enzyme catalyic
>   mechanism, which **provides** an important insight into the molecular
>   basis of XYZ disease.

Overall the sentence is far too wordy, and you haven't even used the full name of the disease. I recommend keeping the supporting framework for these complicated ideas as simple as possible, for example:

> In summary, this work **is** a detailed description of the enzyme
>   catalyic mechanism, which **explains** the molecular basis of XYZ
>   disease.

Comment: You could also replace either instance of provides with `gives`.

Comment: @RobK that is true, please post your own answer. Is mine wrong?

Comment: @WV, thanks for the feedback. While I agree that the original sentence is wordy, IMO, your first answer is more appropriate than the second, as a description of the "normal mechanism" can only provide insights into a disease process but the description per se cannot explain the basis of a disease process.